# Autolayout not producing expected results

Tags: interface-builder, uistackview, ios-autolayout

[image]
On the left is what I expect, on the right is what I get. The second view is a stack view. I have tried various constraints, hugging properties, compression resistance settings, but can't seem to get the expected results. The text does have word wrapping, but it expands regardless of the actual height of the text. With some settings, the stack view expands, some the text view disappears, but I can't get the expected result on the right.

Comment: A little more detail needed. Are `Image` plus three Label-Text "rows" plus orange-label all in a stack view? Is Table View *also* in that stack view? Some other layout?

Comment: Image, table view, and text (orange) are not in the stack view. The stack view has three stack views embedded.

Comment: You need to look at your constraints. I'm assuming you have a Height constraint on your image view... you're allowing the labels and stack view heights to be determined by their contents (no Height constraints)... and it *looks* like maybe you have a Height constraint on your table view? If so, that's causing the orange-text to expand vertically.

Comment: I have the following constraints: the image has a fixed height and is pinned to the top, leading, trailing edges of the safe area; the stack view is pinned to the bottom of the image, leading, trailing edges of the safe area; the orange text field is pinned to the bottom, leading, trailing edges of the stack view; the table is pinned to the bottom of the text, the leading, trailing, and bottom edges of the safe area. I have even put the image and the text inside the stack view with the same results.

Comment: Are your labels all embedded in UIViews? It looks that way, based on the "padding" around the text.

Comment: No, the labels are in a stack view. But, I have one more view in here that I didn't show that seems to be the problem. I have an image view that is pinned to the top of the table view, the leading, trailing, and bottom edges of the safe area. If I, instead, pin the top of this image view to the top of the safe area, all is well (except I don't want the top of that image view at the top of the display.

Comment: Does this "not shown" image view have a height constraint?

Comment: If the labels are not embedded in views, what are you doing to give them leading padding? And, you commented *"the orange text field"* -- is that a `UITextField`? Is it a `UITextView`? Or is it a `UILabel`? The more precise detail you give, the more likely you can get help.